# PrimeFaces How to validate uploaded file name?

Tags: java, validation, file-upload, primefaces

Does any body know how to implement validation  with validation message to uploadFile in PrimeFaces?

**View:**

```
<p:fileUpload id="upload" 
fileUploadListener="#{fileBean.handleFileUpload}"
update="uploads" auto="true" multiple="true" skinSimple="true"> 
<f:validator validatorId="uploadValidator"/>
<p> <h:messages id="messages" /></p>
</p:fileUpload>
```

**FileBean:**

```
List<UploadedFile> uploadedFiles;

    public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {
        if (uploadedFiles == null) {
            uploadedFiles = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        uploadedFiles.add(event.getFile());
    }
```

**uploadValidator.java**

```
@FacesValidator("uploadValidator")
public class UploadValidator implements Validator {
    @Override
    public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException {
        Part file = (Part) value;
        FacesMessage message=null;

        try {
            if (!file.getName().matches("\\w+"))
                message=new FacesMessage("Wrong file name");
            if (message!=null && !message.getDetail().isEmpty())
            {
                message.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
                throw new ValidatorException(message);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage(ex.getMessage()));
        }
    }
}
```

I need to check if uploaded file name is on Latin Unicode and if not - show  user a message "Wrong file name." My code doesn't work. No message is displayed no matter the file name.

Thank you.

Comment: does the file Name enough for you ???

Comment: Yagami Light, sorry I did not get your question. What did u mean?

Comment: Your question isn't clear , do you want to know if there is a method to say if this file name is in Latin Unicode ???

Comment: @ Yagami Light, In my code I have override validate method to check if Unicode is latin. In debug mode it works good. Validation message is generated. But the problem is that that validation message is never shown to user.

Comment: try to use `<p:message for="upload" /> instead `<p> <h:messages id="messages" /></p>`

Comment: Nope, that didn't help.  Validation runs but message is not displayed on view.

Comment: Try to add an other message type like `MyUtil.addErrorMessage("ERROR");` in your `ManagedBean` and don't forget to use `<p:messages id="messages" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true" closable="true" />` example in http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/message/messages.xhtml

Comment: @ Yagami Light, thank u a lot. U helped me to solve the issue!

Comment: @ Yagami Light, yes, please.

Comment: the solution is done if there is any thing valuable to add please edit it

Comment: what is class is PART ? Part file = (Part) value; ? fullname please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is many way's to make a message appear from your managedBean

***From your Entity***

entity.java

```
@NotEmpty(message = "{validation.msg.notNull}")
@NotBlank(message = "{validation.msg.notBlank}")
@Column(name = "code", unique = true)
private String code;
```

and in your page.xhtml

```
<p:inputText id="code" ...  />
<p:message for="code" />
```

The big + with this solution that if the `p:inputText` is `NotEmpty` and `NotBlank`  the informations doesn't even go to the entity level, and you don't have to make a condition to verify if the `p:inputText` is `NotEmpty` and `NotBlank` in your managedBean

***From your ManagedBean***

page.xhtml

```
<p:messages id="msgs" globalOnly="true" showDetail="true" closable="true"/>
<p:inputText id="code" ...  />
<p:commandButton  ... actionListener="#{managedBean.validate()}" update=":msgs"  />
```

and in your ManagedBean.java

```
public void validate(){
...
MyUtil.addErrorMessage("ERROR");
...
}
```

You can find the best example in the [Primefaces messages example web site](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/message/messages.xhtml) and the growl message is also a good way to show a message [Primefaces growl example web site](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/message/growl.xhtml).

Hope that helped you.