# client validation in p:messages with "for" attribute

Tags: primefaces

The follwing is work fine. the client validation error shows in p:messages

```
<p:panelGrid >
....
....
....
<p:commandButton value="Save" validateClient="true" update="save-gje"
                        action="#{generalJournalEntryMB.AddGeneralJournalEntry}" ajax="true" process="top-menu-and-form" />
                </p:panelGrid>
                <p:messages closable="true" id="save-gje" />
```

but when I add "for" attribute , its not working for client validation.

```
<p:messages closable="true" id="save-gje" for="save-gje" />
```

how can I show client validation in p:messages with **"for"** attribute?

Comment: Does it work for server side validations? And are ypu sure p:messages has a 'for' attribute?

Comment: the `for` attribut work for an `id` that perform an action example a commandButton that that need's a message after submetting an information, that's meen you can't make it like this

Comment: look to this example i think it show's what i meant in my first comment `<p:inputText id="code"  ...> </p:inputText> <p:message for="code" />` this how message works the solution is to make in the head of the page and update

Comment: look to this post it will made it clear [PrimeFaces How to validate uploaded file name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41441288/primefaces-how-to-validate-uploaded-file-name/41458749#41458749)

Comment: @Kukeltje yes, its work for server side validarion. but stop for client side. How an I make it , to work for both clent side and server side ?

Comment: @YagamiLight how can I use <p:messages with multiple for attibute ? for example `<p:message for="code, id, name" />` .  or how can we display client side validation and server side valiation messgae in one place ?

Comment: @ShahidGhafoor did yo u see my answer

Comment: @YagamiLight yup I seen, but its not my requirement. as update work for me as well . but question is that when I put for attribute , update gone stop :(

Comment: make the p:messages under the element that you want to work with inputext ...

Comment: @YagamiLight is it not possible to add multiple values in for attribute ? for example  `<p:inputText id="id" ...  /> <p:inputText id="code" ...  /> <p:inputText id="name" ...  />` and Primefaces Messages something like `<p:message for="id, code, name" />`

Comment: non don't think so just flow the example that you see in the primefaces site or the example that i provide in my solution